# Is there a way to hide/show documents in a pdf portfolio created using adobe flash builder and the portfolio api filtered by the document metadata?

Tags: api, adobe, flash-builder, portfolio

I am currently working on a PDF portfolio which essentially lets the user select their language. Depending on their selection, I want a to filter which documents are displayed (by showing on those which have a specified keyword in their metadata).

Currently, I am unsure of 2 things and require assistance on:

1. Whether a documents metadata (especially a pdf keyword field) can be reached using the portfolio API.
2. Whether documents inside a PDF portfolio can be hidden from the user.

If anyone has any thoughts around this area please discuss with me. I would greatly appreciate it.

Augier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to these two questions can be found here in my related posts:

[How can I open an Attachment from a PDF Portfolio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015162/how-can-i-open-an-attachment-from-a-pdf-portfolio)

[Using the Flex 4 API, how can I access data from a PDF in an adobe PDF portfolio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930448/using-the-flex-4-api-how-can-i-access-data-from-a-pdf-in-an-adobe-pdf-portfolio)