# Using the Flex 4 API, how can I access data from a PDF in an adobe PDF portfolio?

Tags: flex4, adobe, flash-builder, portfolio

I am creating a PDF portfolio and need to access data from a PDF, to be precise the related *keyword* metadata.

Could someone point me in the direction of method to do this?

Regards,

Augier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was:

```
IAttachment(item).getFieldValue('Title');
```

This would find the Title attribute of this attachment