# How can I open an Attachment from a PDF Portfolio?

Tags: apache-flex, acrobat

I'm currently creating a PDF portfolio which displays data in a dataGrid. There are a number of attachments and when I doubleclick the specific attachment I would like it to display in a new acrobat/reader window.

Could anyone instruct me?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I was having serious issues accessing the host using a flex4 project.

This led me to switching to flex3 because I had found many examples of code that works just fine.

These examples can be found [here](http://pdfdevjunkie.host.adobe.com/00_helloWorld.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this cannot be done in a web-based Flash file. It must be done in an AIR Application.

See [this Adobe article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS2A7C0A31-A6A9-42d2-8772-79166A98A085). Relevant information:

> In **AIR 2**, you can open a file using the application registered by
>   the operating system to open it. For example, an AIR application can
>   open a DOC file with the application registered to open it. Use the
>   openWithDefaultApplication() method of a File object to open the file.

You can use `FileReference` to allow the user to save the PDF to their system, but I do not believe there is a way to force it to open within an application. In fact, I don't think you can force an application to open via a download (without user permission, anyway) via standard JS/PHP methods either (I'm not a master of either of these, so I could be wrong there)

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough. I creating a PDF portfolio. This is a PDF with attachments inside it. I have customised it to view them in a data grid view but cannot open the attachments.

Comment: Crap. I completely misunderstood you. Sorry about that.